# Why does nothing happen when i choose j-link in Segger SystemView?

Tags: embedded, freertos, rtos, segger-jlink, system-views

I want to start using SystemView to trace my FreeRTOS usage on STM32F767 nucleo boards.

When i click on the green triangle "Start Recording", and after asking about, J-Link confirm, then nothing happens. (I have tried all version from 3.12 to 3.52a)

I also tried Target -> Recorder Configuration->J-link -> OK, an then nothing happen again.In my experience , the system view should display the window to select chip part number,etc.

I have follow step by step with the User Guide and stuck with this. Hope somebody help me, thanks all.
[image]

Comment: Assuring us that you have followed the user guide is a platitude.  Better to explicitly state what you have done?  For example have you [instrumented the RTOS](https://www.segger.com/doc/UM08027_SystemView.html#Instrumenting_OSes_and_software_modules) or are you using a provided instrumented build?  Segger's own embOS comes with an out of the box instrumented build, but I doubt FreeRTOS does.

Comment: Oh, I just checked and discovered I haven't downloaded the J-Link Software. I thought I had followed all the steps correctly, but I was missing the first step. Thank you very much. 
Thanks, sir. Here's what I do:
1. Installing J-Link.
2. Converting ST-Link to J-Link.
3. Installing Segger Ozone.
4. Attaching Ozone to the MCU.
5. Installing SystemView: Download SystemView V3.52a, Source code configuration
6. Using Systemview.

Comment: @ThuongDuong - do not just put this list of steps you went through into a comment to your question, but please edit it and describe the steps there.